# Cannot convert value of type '[Message]' to expected argument type 'Message'

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm following [this](https://youtu.be/hz1h_ColGy0?t=13m1s) tutorial and I'm getting the error that you can see in the title, here is my code:

```
func loadData()
{
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    if let context = delegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    {
        if let friends = fetchFriends()
        {
            messages = [Message]()

            for friend in friends
            {
                print(friend.name) // This line btw for some reason is giving me: Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to Any

                let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Message> = Message.fetchRequest()
                fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
                fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.name = %@", friend.name!)
                fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

                do
                {
                    let fetchedMessages = try(context.fetch(fetchRequest))
                    messages?.append(fetchedMessages)
                    // This above line is the line which is giving me this error:
                    //Cannot convert value of type '[Message]' to expected argument type 'Message'
                }
                catch let err
                {
                    print(err)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from about 13min my code does not look exactly the same, since the video is a bit old and using an older version of swift.

I'm hoping someone can help me to solve the error since I do not know what to do, thank you in advance.

Comment: You should write this - print(friend.name as Any) or print(friend.name!) to silence the warning as the friend.name is an optional which you have not unwrapped.

The error that you are getting means that you are passing an 'array' of Message type instead of passing a single 'Message' object to the append method.

Edit: As mentioned below by some users you have to append the contents of fetchedMessages array to the messages array i.e. append every element one by one. Your mistake is you simply try to append the whole array to the messages array. Hope you understood.

Comment: Ahh ok I understand now why it didn't work, I had written the code as in the video which used the old version of the append function so xcode corrected it to what I currently had which did not work, but I tried Moayad Al kouz solution which worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below line

```
messages.append(contentsOf: fetchedMessages)
```

instead of: `messages.append(fetchedMessages)`

Answer (score 1):

`append` is to append individual elements to an array. You can use `+=` to concatenate two arrays.

```
messages! += fetchedMessages
```

If `messages` is of optional type, you can force unwrap it because you know you have already set it to an empty array, but frankly, I would no make `messages` optional - just initialise it to []